# how to reconfigure mysql-server

Tags: 18.04, mysql

I want to setup mysql-server again but I am not sure how to do it.
I have tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server` but it does not do anything.

output of ps aux | grep mysql:

```
matthew   9288  0.0  0.0  13136  1044 pts/1    S+   19:02   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

The `mysql-server` package isn't itself reconfigurable: as noted in `apt show mysql-server` it is just a dependency package:

```
 This is an empty package that depends on the current "best" version of
 mysql-server (currently mysql-server-5.7), as determined by the MySQL
 maintainers. Install this package if in doubt about which MySQL version
 you need. That will install the version recommended by the package
 maintainers.
```

You can see what the *actual* reconfigurable server package is by querying the `debconf` database:

```
$ debconf-show --listowners | grep mysql
mysql-server-5.7
```

So, in my case it should be

```
dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
```

Comment: Admittedly I haven't spent a ton of time researching this, [debconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/debconf.7.html) is a great command because it only shows the server, while `dpkg -l | grep mysql` shows more mysql-related packages. I wonder why? Interesting from that linked man page that `dkpg-reconfigure debconf` is a useful feature.

Comment: And interestingly this appears to work only up to mysqld 5.7.24 or 25? On mysql-server-5.7 (.26) when I run the `dpkg-reconfigure` command I get `This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.26, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade` -- I know a lot about Linux, etc but learning some mysql today!

Answer (score 1):

Have you stopped `mysql`/`mysqld`?

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

You should ask the system to start, stop or restart `mysql`.  This is done using `systemctl` on newer systems, or `service` on older systems.  [You can find more details here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers).

The first requirement for running MySQL is to understand how to administer a Linux system.  Use and understanding of `systemctl` is critical.

Now, try to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server`. 
 You have to make sure that no MySQL process is running in order to reconfigure it.  If you continue running into issues, see if there are any other processes running and `kill` them:

```
sudo ps aux | grep mysql
mysql     8681  1.9  8.6 1350976 175128 ?      Sl   18:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
matthew   8788  0.0  0.0  13136  1044 pts/1    S+   18:52   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
sudo kill 8681
```

You should always use `systemctl` when possible, and only kill the service this way if you truly need to.  This is for many reasons, including for the health of your database.  By failing to use `systemctl` one possible problem will be that the PID file ( `/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid` ) may not be properly cleaned up, making it difficult for you to start the service again.

[steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079794/13247) has the missing piece.

Comment: why does it say mysql is not installed when it is `matthew@matthewserver:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql
dpkg-query: package 'mysql' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql is not installed
`

Comment: I was wrong about that.  I've edited the answer.  Are you saying that after stopping the service, you you're still not getting the desired output from `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server`?  Can you edit your question to show the output of `sudo ps aux | grep mysql`

Comment: i have edited it

Comment: Ah, so the point I'm trying to make is that so long as `mysql` is running, as it is shown to be in your output, you cannot reconfigure it.  Typically, you want to stop the service using `systemctl`.  If that fails you, then you can `kill` the process.  `sudo kill 8681`.  You should really, really try using `systemctl` though.

Comment: killed it, still does not work

Comment: Can you re-run the `ps` command and update your answer?  Thank you for trying that out.

Comment: i edited it....

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something but if steedriver's answer has the missing piece, it would be helpful if you clarify that by continuing the statement, "...has the missing piece, which is..." presumably that we need to dig for the actual reconfigurable package name and use that? I would think you can put that full statement in your answer and credit steeldriver for that bit of info, hope that helps?

Comment: otherwise this is a very helpful answer :) +1